# How to query Athena to get records in the last hour using partitions

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I have some JSON data in an S3 bucket that is partitioned by multiple folders, each folder represents a partition with a name that corresponds to the datetime that the data was added to S3, here is the structure:

```
bucket:
--- 2023-10-18-10-08/ (Folder containing data that was created at 10:08 on October 18th)
--- 2023-10-18-10-42/
--- 2023-10-18-11-10/
--- 2023-10-18-11-42/ (Folder containing data that was created at 11:42 on October 18th)
```

A glue crawler is running against the bucket every hour and the folders respresent partitions in the generated tab. I would like to query the data from last hour (meaning if `current_time` is 12:05, I would like to query data from partition `2023-10-18-11-10` and `2023-10-18-11-42` only.

How is it possible to achieve this for a given hour ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If using Athena to query the data, something similar to this should work:

```sql
WITH dataset AS (
  SELECT '2023-10-16-10-08' AS partition_column UNION ALL
  SELECT '2023-10-18-09-42' UNION ALL
  SELECT '2023-10-18-10-42' UNION ALL
  SELECT '2023-10-18-11-10' UNION ALL
  SELECT '2023-10-19-11-42'
)
SELECT *
FROM dataset
WHERE 
  CAST( -- Step 2: Convert the constructed timestamp string to timestamp type
    CONCAT( -- Step 1: Convert 'YYYY-MM-DD-HH-MM' to an ISO 8601 timestamp string 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MI:SS'
        SUBSTRING(partition_column, 1, 10), -- Gets 'YYYY-MM-DD'
        ' ',
        SUBSTRING(partition_column, 12, 2), -- Gets 'HH'
        ':',
        SUBSTRING(partition_column, 15, 2), -- Gets 'MM'
        ':00' -- Adds seconds
    ) AS timestamp
  ) BETWEEN 
    (date_trunc('hour', current_timestamp) - INTERVAL '1' HOUR) AND -- current time minus one hour
    date_trunc('hour', current_timestamp) -- current time
;
```

This query:

1. Starts with an example CTE containing a column similar to your partition column in S3.
2. Takes that CTE, converts the partition column to a timestamp using some basic string manipulation.
3. Creates a filter on the converted timestamp to be `BETWEEN` the previous hour and the current hour. It does this by truncating the current_timestamp to the hour & then subtracting an hour from this timestamp. For example: If the current_timestamp is `2023-01-01 03:03:03`, it would become `2023-01-01 02:00:00`. So the `BETWEEN` clause would be: `WHERE partition_column BETWEEN 2023-01-01 02:00:00 AND 2023-01-01 03:00:00`

**Note: This assumes the partitions are using the UTC timezone, since `current_timestamp` returns the current time in UTC**

(caveat that this might not be the optimal way to convert the partition to a timestamp - See the presto [docs](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html) for other ways)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it was key to understand how I should proceed, I ended up using `date_parse` function instead of `CAST` and `CONCAT`